# How to stop keyboard popping issue is TextField flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

In this app when I write something in the search bar and press the done button in keyboard and then press the cross button it show the keyboard and close it again .How to stop popping of the keyboard .

```
    Widget _search() {
       return Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
       child: TextField(
        onSubmitted: (s){
          //
        },
        controller: _controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed: () {
              _controller.clear();
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
              
            },
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF9ad3bc)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF9ad3bc)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
          ),
          hintText: 'Search..',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

if I don't press the done button (in keyboard) the keyboard remain in the screen and it work perfectly .
But if I don't close the keyboard the popup issue arise .
[image]

Comment: Remove requestFocus line in your clear button onPressed.

Comment: then it will never close the keyboard .

Comment: Then instead of requestFocus use unFocus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating the focus node only locally do like this:

```
 @override
 void initState() {
    //rest of your code
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    super.initState();
 }
```

Then in the text field add

```
focusNode: _focusNode(),
```

In the onSubmitted method add:

```
_focusNode.unfocus();
```

Comment: After the change, if I do the same thing the keyboard pop up but don't close

Comment: It doesn't close when you submit?

Comment: It close when I submit ,But it is not the problem .The problem is when I submit and then press the cross icon(to clear and unfocus the text field) the keyboard pop up and down like in the gif .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify my question. I was talking about my solution. The keyboard never closes or doesn't close only in a specific situation? By the way I've done for one of my projects something similar here: https://github.com/AndreaCostanzo1/FlutterApp/blob/444fb42238fcbca646cc755691a6f1865a9baa0a/lib/view/pages/fragments/fragments_wmax_medium/search_fragment.dart#L118.
The bar automatically closes when it's empty, and does a real-time search.